# Find matrix with minimum number of nonzero elements to satisfy row and column sums

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity

The problem is to find a matrix that has given *row and column sums* and has a *minimum number of nonzero elements*. Given two arrays of positive integers `A[1...N]` and `B[1...M]`, `sum(A)=sum(B)`. The arrays A and B are row and column sums respectively of an unknown NxM matrix. The elements of the matrix are non-negative integers.

Is this possible in polynomial time?

Equivalent formulation - create a minimum size multi-set C that can be created from A and from B by "breaking up numbers in smaller pieces". The multi-set C is the same as nonzero elements from the matrix. The obvious lower and upper bounds on the size of C are:

```
max(|A|, |B|) <= |C| <= N+M-1
```

Comment: Curious. How did you get the limit: |C| <= N+M-1

Comment: Nevermind. I got it

Comment: If you represent numbers by line segments and line up A with B there is going to be at most N+M-1 segments between the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned earlier |C| <= N + M - 1

But, say you can split A and B into A1, A2 and B1, B2 such that sum(A1) = sum(B1) and sum(A2) = sum(B2), the constraint becomes smaller

```
|C| <= (|A1| + |B1| -1) + (|A2| + |B2| -1)
    <= N + M - 2
```

So the goal of the problem is to split A and B into the maximum number of components A1, A2, ... Ak and B1, B2, ... Bk such that sum(Ai) = sum(Bi). In which case:

```
 |C| <= N + M -1 -k
```

I don't think there is a polynomial solution to this. But the following heuristics might work.

Step 1: Sort A and B

Step 2: Find common elements between A and B and move them out into their own components

Step 3: Find sets of two elements in A that sum to an element in B and move them out. Do the same thing for two elements in B that sum to an element in A

Step 4: ....

As you can see, it becomes harder and harder as the size of the component keeps going up. But I am not sure if there is a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not work. Here is a counterexample: A=[2, 10, 101, 1001], B=[1, 1, 12, 100, 1000]. If you match [2] from A with [1,1] from B you will end up with a wrong answer.